# Sending custom comment objects back and forth via salesforce2salesforce

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

What are the best practices when sending comment objects through Salesforce2salesforce?

Comment objects are objects that have a Master-Detail relationship with the parent object, and are made specifically for custom objects like orders where the Notes & Attachments are considered not enough.

like if I have:
CustomObject1 with CommentObject1 in one SF org
CustomObject2 with CommentObject2 in the other

When trying to send this over with S2S, i'm thinking one method would be to send the parentID of CommentObject1 into CommentObject2 and store it in a hidden field.  Likewise when they are sent back (or forwarded).   Thus a trigger could fire on update that looks for the original parentobjectID and knows which CustomObject to attach it to.  Are there any drawbacks to this approach that i'm not seeing? I'm guessing that every time the connection is forwarded, the Id placeholder field would be overwritten, but that should be OK since it should always be the same Id.

Comment: Can you utilise external IDs in SF2SF?

Comment: We went the route of utilizing the ID'

Comment: @akarnid Can you please self-answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

We decided that this was too much hassle and simply used a text field on the record itself to keep track of comments.